# How to save form asp.net content with jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I don't know how to implement `ASP.Net Core MVC` script to save the form content append through `jquery`.
The `"Save"` button is found in the `form`

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#supplierId').load("/AgentService/SuppliersList");
        });

        function AddSup() {
            let a = $('#supTable tr').length;
            $("#supTable").append('<tr id="' + a + 'tr")"><td> <div class="form-group"> <span id="supplierId' + a + '"></span> </div> </td> <td><div class="form-group"><button onclick="DeleteSup(' + a + ')" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">&#x2613;</button></div></td> </tr>');
            $('#supplierId' + a).load("/AgentService/SuppliersList");
        }

        function DeleteSup(id) {
            $('#' + id + 'tr').remove();
        }

        function Save() {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Service agent',
                text: 'Edited',
                icon: 'success',
                confirmButtonText: false,
                showConfirmButton: false
            })
        }

    </script>

<div class="form-group">
    <table id="supTable" class="table table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="supplierId"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><div class="form-group"><button onclick="DeleteSup(@i)" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">&#x2613;</button></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="AddSup()">Add supplier</button>
</div>

<hr />

<form asp-action="edit" method="post">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="Save()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add your controller code that you are trying to receive form values for binding to model? And also you could share model class as well.

Comment: thank's sslslslslsls